# What architecture is bi-endian at runtime?

Tags: linux-kernel, architecture

If I understand correctly x86_64 is a **bi-arch**, since it supports running native x86 and x86_64 at the same time (no reboot, no reconfiguration). ia64 is a single arch and does not support x86.

I am trying to understand which architecture supported by the Linux kernel can run in true **bi-endian** mode, so that the CPU can switch endianess at runtime.

I could not find definitive answer for the following arch namely ppc64(le) and mips64(le) (eg. MIPS64r6). Does one of those support running of (no reboot, no reconfiguration) respectively ppc32(be) and mips32(be) (eg. MIPS32r2) ? Maybe something in the ARM family also ?

Comment: x86_64 can only run the 32bit subset of x86 (not legacy 16 bit, 8bit, or 4bit). Have you seen (can remember which architecture), has spiral endien: It did one endian when it went from 8 to 16bit, and the other from 16bit to 32 bit (like how americans write there dates (weird). Have a look at arm, if I remember correct, this CPU supports both at run time, though there may not be any kernel/tool support for mixing them.

Comment: This isn’t authoritative, but the [`ppc64el` architecture qualification page](https://wiki.debian.org/ArchiveQualification/ppc64el) says that “A multi-arch arrangement with the other ports is not feasible, since the kernel doesn't support bi-endianness.” and I get the impression that the statement on the kernel is general. The [`mips64el` page](https://wiki.debian.org/ArchiveQualification/mips64el) only mentions the other little-endian MIPS architectures. I’m not aware of any endianness-swapping support in the kernel’s thunking layers.